# Format Dynamic Text Using PHP

Tags: php, vb.net

I have text fields which are populated from a database, the text when entered by the user is punctuated correctly with full stops and carriage returns etc.

Using VB with an ordinary db request:

```
<%=(rsMyrecordset.Fields.Item("text").Value)%>
```

I would get this result:

```
Mary had a little Lamb. Its fleece was as white as snow.
```

even if the user entered a return after the full stop after the word Lamb.

Using this code:

```
<%= Replace(rsMyRecordset.Fields.Item("text").Value, VbCrLf, "<br>") %>
```

The text returned would be:

```
Mary had a little Lamb.
Its fleece was as white as snow.
```

How would I achieve the same result using PHP?  Currently I have:

```
<?php echo $row_rsMyRecordset['text']; ?>
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you are looking for nl2br: http://php.net/manual/function.nl2br.php

```
<?php echo nl2br($row_rsMyRecordset['text']); ?>
```